# Using this and document.getElementById within an img onmouseover function

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover, onmouseout

I'm trying to change an image and the text inside an h2 using `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`, like in this gif

[image]

I give some examples below where I can change the image with `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` using either `this` or `document.getElementById`, but when I use `this` I can't figure out how to simultaneously change the text inside the h2 tag(like in the example under `document.getElementById`). Using the following snippet does not change the image.

```
onmouseover='(function(){
                this.src="https://i.imgur.com/dsF2mgL.jpg"
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="I am so very tired"
            })()'
```

I am looking for a way to use `this` and change both the image and the text inside the h2

---

**Using `document.getElementById`**

```html
    <h2>ICE 14: Drake the Duck</h2>
    <img
        id="duck"   
        src="https://i.imgur.com/G8TcUqA.jpg"
        onmouseover='(function(){
            //this.src="./duck2.jpg"
            document.getElementById("duck").src="https://i.imgur.com/dsF2mgL.jpg"
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="I am so very tired"
        })()'
        onmouseout='(function(){
            document.getElementById("duck").src="https://i.imgur.com/PKi5s3p.jpg"
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Now I am wide awake!"
        })()'
    >
    <h2 id="message">I am Drake the Duck.</h2>
```

**Using `this`**

```html
        <h2>ICE 14: Drake the Duck</h2>
        <img
            id="duck"   
            src="https://i.imgur.com/G8TcUqA.jpg"
            onmouseover='this.src="https://i.imgur.com/dsF2mgL.jpg"'
            onmouseout='this.src="https://i.imgur.com/PKi5s3p.jpg"'
        >
        <h2 id="message">I am Drake the Duck.</h2>
```

Comment: You definitely don't want `getElementById`. When the browser raises the event, it passes you an event object so you don't need `this` either. `function(event) { var img = event.target; var h2 = img.previousSibling;}`. The problem with this method of retrieving the H2 is that it is brutal. If your markup structure changes it will fail

Comment: @rayhatfield It is in the example under 'Using `this`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an IIFE in the `onclick` attribute, because `this` is not inherited by functions (unless you use an arrow function). You can just put the code directly in the `onclick` attribute without the function wrapper.

```html
<h2>ICE 14: Drake the Duck</h2>
<img id="duck" src="https://i.imgur.com/G8TcUqA.jpg"
    onmouseover='this.src="https://i.imgur.com/dsF2mgL.jpg"; document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="I am so very tired"' 
    onmouseout='this.src="https://i.imgur.com/PKi5s3p.jpg"; document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Now I am wide awake!"'>
<h2 id="message">I am Drake the Duck.</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **this** keyword alone won't get you far as it is just a reference to the element that caused the event i.e. the `<img>` element in your case.

However if the `<h2>` element is always the next sibling after your `<img>` you can query the image's **.nextElementSibling** property to get a reference to the `<h2>` and assign the text.

Here's an example:

```html
<h2>ICE 14: Drake the Duck</h2>
<img id="duck" src="https://i.imgur.com/G8TcUqA.jpg" onmouseover='this.src="https://i.imgur.com/dsF2mgL.jpg";this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML="Now I am wide awake!"' onmouseout='this.src="https://i.imgur.com/PKi5s3p.jpg";this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML="I am so very tired!"'>
<h2 id="message">I am Drake the Duck.</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `nextElementSibling` selector to ahive it

```html
<h2>ICE 14: Drake the Duck</h2>
<img id="duck" src="https://i.imgur.com/G8TcUqA.jpg" onmouseover='this.src="https://i.imgur.com/dsF2mgL.jpg"
    nextElementSibling.textContent="I am so very tired"' onmouseout='this.src="https://i.imgur.com/PKi5s3p.jpg"
    nextElementSibling.textContent="Now I am wide awake!"'>
<h2 id="message">I am Drake the Duck.</h2>
```